# Understanding jQuery .change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

I have some issue understanding the `jQuery().change()` behavior.

The HTML is basically a lot of input elements - checkboxes ( each with ID of `id^='o99-post-visible-XXX'` - and they are pure CSS images as Checkboxes, but this is irrelevant ) and I have another checkbox (`"#o99-check-all"`) to "check all" and a text input field (`'#o99-post-visible-ids'`) that receives the IDs of the selected boxes.

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#o99-check-all").change(function () {
       jQuery("input:checkbox[id^='o99-post-visible-']").prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked")).trigger('change');

    });

        var checkboxes = jQuery("input.o99-cbvu-posts-checkbox:checkbox");
        checkboxes.on('change', function() {
            // get IDS from all selected checkboxes and make a comma separated string
            var ids = checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                return this.value;
            }).get().join(',');
            // put IDS inside a text input field
            jQuery('#o99-post-visible-ids').val(ids);
            // console.log(ids);
        });
    });
```

Now, more or less everything works now, but that is not the issue.

at first , the first chunk of code was:

```
  jQuery("#o99-check-all").change(function () {
           // without .trigger('change') chained
           jQuery("input:checkbox[id^='o99-post-visible-']").prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked"));

        });
```

and it did not work ( why?? ) - meaning the boxes were selected as expected but the `'#o99-post-visible-ids'` input field was not receiving the IDs - until I chained a `.trigger('change')` event - when suddenly it works well.

my confusion is with the following ( which perhaps for my little understanding of jQuery internal works is counter-intuitive )

after chain adding `.trigger('change')` - isn't it somehow an endless loop where a `chain()` event is trigger inside a listener of `change()` ? and if not why?

Why is the code functioning now and did not function correctly before? because again, for my understanding, there was a change, even if not triggered by direct user click. Why would I need to trigger it manually?

Comment: Checking/unchecking checkboxes by code wont raise events see https://jsfiddle.net/wzkr5gtf/

Comment: @Viney - thank , that would explain it ( like more or less Bram Vanroy answer ) but if the `.trigger('change')` will indeed raise the event - what about the "infinite loop" that confused me ?

Comment: I don't see any loop there , trigger gets called on each checkbox one by one

Comment: that's probably my misunderstanding . in the first chunk the `.change(function ..()` is nested with a `.trigger('change')` event .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What is happening now, is that whenever you change the *all* checkbox, the other checkboxes will be checked/unchecked the same as *all*, and then the `change` event is triggered.

Because you added a listener for `change`, that function will then fire. I.e. this function will run:

```
function() {
    // get IDS from all selected checkboxes and make a comma separated string
    var ids = checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                  return this.value;
              }).get().join(',');
    // put IDS inside a text input field
    jQuery('#o99-post-visible-ids').val(ids);
    // console.log(ids);
}
```

Without your `.trigger("change")` (or `.change()` in short), you *only* change a property of the inputs. So the object changes, indeed, but that does not mean the `change` event is triggered. It does sound counter-intuitive, but events are only triggered by user actions or if you call the event explicitly - in no other way do events get triggered.

Comment: so just to confirm that I understand - you are saying that basically the `change()` event can only be triggered by a user interaction and not by any other change that is made with another jQuery function . - that would explain it - at least in my head .. but is there a way to indeed listen to such an event ( triggered by internal function ) in a more efficient way ? because the above code just seems like an ugly hack .. also - what about the part of the seeming "infinite-loop"

Comment: That is correct. If you have attached a listener (`.on("change")`), that function will only be *triggered* by user-interaction, or if you explicitly call the change event. It is not a hack, don't worry. This is how it is normally done. Where do you see an infinite loop? I don't see it. You never call .change in the .on("change")?

Comment: in the first chunk i have `.change(function ()..)` with a `trigger('change')` inside .. I understand that this is not an event but a function .. but still - a bit confusing ..

Comment: Yes, but you are chaining it to different elements. `.change(function())` is on the *all* checkbox, and the trigger is on the other divs. So when you trigger change on the other checkboxes, this does not influence the *all* checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

its because you have written `jQuery('#o99-post-visible-ids').val(ids);` inside a function which happens only when the change event done on the inputs, assigning prop directly through `.prop` does not trigger the `change` event and so the result handler wont run

Answer (score 0):

Now if I understand you correctly...

...because you're giving every check box the **same ID**? If you wish to apply it to more than a single element, it is best practice to **use a class selector instead**.

```
jQuery(".o99-check-all").change(function () {
// without .trigger('change') chained
jQuery(".o99-check-all").prop('checked', jQuery(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

See link 
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: well - either I misunderstand the answer or in fact you understand wrong - the ID is only for the ONE `"check - all"` checkbox ( probably my fault - I maybe should have included the markup - but i was afraid it will be too long )

Comment: You don't have to add chain anything. Just refer to it by class. If you refer to it by ID it will cause all types of ambiguous errors. I've also added a link to JQuery change event handler to clarify more.

Comment: If I refer to it by class how could I collect the IDS ( which is the ultimate goal ) . do you mean only collect the objects by class ?